# Display Specific Categories posts on the home page

Tags: posts, categories

I want to display categories posts in the following format on the front home:

Health:
1st post   2nd post   3rd post

Fitness:
1st post   2nd post   3rd post

Beauty
1st post   2nd post   3rd post

Example site: beautyhealthtips.in

Does anybody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_excluded_post_ids( $exclude_post_ids, $posts ) {
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        array_push( $exclude_post_ids, $post->ID );
    }
    return $exclude_post_ids;
}

$exclude_post_ids = array();

$latest_posts = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 3
) );
$exclude_post_ids = add_excluded_post_ids( $exclude_post_ids, $latest_posts );

$health_posts = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 3,
    'category' => get_category_by_slug( 'health' )->term_id, // Change accordingly
    'exclude' => $exclude_post_ids
) );
$exclude_post_ids = add_excluded_post_ids( $exclude_post_ids, $latest_posts );

$fitness_posts = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 3,
    'category' => get_category_by_slug( 'fitness' )->term_id, // Change accordingly
    'exclude' => $exclude_post_ids
) );
$exclude_post_ids = add_excluded_post_ids( $exclude_post_ids, $fitness_posts );

$beauty_posts = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 3,
    'category' => get_category_by_slug( 'beauty' )->term_id, // Change accordingly
    'exclude' => $exclude_post_ids
) );
```

Now you have $latest_posts, $health_posts, $fitness_posts and $beauty_posts. Each one of them stores a set of 3 posts which you can use to generate your HTML. You can use a shortcode that outputs the whole HTML, then insert this shortcode within a "Page" and finally set your homepage to that "Static page".

Note $health_posts, $fitness_posts and $beauty_posts will store the latest posts that belong to those categories, respectively. If you wish to retrieve those posts by another parameter, like amount of views, or randomly, you'll have to use `WP_Query` instead of `get_posts()`.

Comment: Thanks, @eduardo-escobar But this code is showing an error while saving in functions.php file - syntax error, unexpected ''exclude'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'

Comment: Syntax error, i just fixed it.

Comment: Ok added successfully. Can you please tell what will be the shortcode?. Some categories have - hyphen like health-care, what will be the code for that $health_care_posts or something else?

Comment: @rudyards you need to investigate a little mate, i'd say half the job is done with that code.

Comment: Ok Thanks but nothing happened with after adding that code in function file.